# Permission denied (publickey,password). rsync: connection unexpectedly closed - gitlab

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gitlab

I created a `gitlab` server. when I want to deploy I got this error message:

```
$ eval $(ssh-agent -s)
Agent pid 258
$ mkdir -p ~/.ssh
$ echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" >> ~/.ssh/id_dsa
$ chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_dsa
$ echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config
$ rsync  -azlh -e 'ssh -p 5432' $CI_PROJECT_DIR/ root@*.**.***.****:/var/www/html/****.com/public_html/
Warning: Permanently added '[*.***.**.***]:5432' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(235) [sender=3.1.2]
Cleaning up file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

my server is ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

If your GitLab server version is more recent than 11.0 (June 2018), keep in mind that **`id_dsa`** ('dsa', not 'rsa') is marked as "deprecated" in ["GitLab and SSH keys" documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/#supported-ssh-key-types):

See "**[Support for DSA SSH keys](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2018/06/22/gitlab-11-0-released/#support-for-dsa-ssh-keys)**"

> Due to published weakness in the ssh-dsa algorithm, we’ll wind down support for DSA SSH keys.
> In 11.0, the default value for the DSA SSH keys setting is “Are forbidden”. This setting is located in the visibility and access controls section of the Settings admin panel.
>
> This setting may be overridden if desired.
> **Beginning in 12.0, GitLab will always reject DSA SSH keys**.
>
> Planned removal date: June 22, 2018

It is best to create keys like:

```sh
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "<comment>"
# or
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048 -C "<comment>"
```